# WP: Can please give explaination what token is in GetPathFromToken

Tags: windows-phone-8, token, media-library

The MediaLibraryExtensions.GetPathFromToken has 2 parameters (MediaLibrary library, string token) as input. I assume the API returns path of specified media item from media library, The token is associated with the media of interest. However, how do I find out the "token" of the media, say a music file in media library? Could please show me how to figure out the "token" from a given Song? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of Token is supplied to an application on a query string when that application is registered to extend various parts of the Windows Phone OS, this includes [Photo Share Picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), [Photo Edit Picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662932%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [Auto Launch from a File Association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

All the examples use [GetPictureFromToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.getpicturefromtoken.aspx), but you can imagine the same scenario with other media types being 'Launched' via file association.

Here's a sample of how to use token with GetPicturesFromToken

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Get a dictionary of query string keys and values.
    IDictionary<string, string> queryStrings = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;

    // Ensure that there is at least one key in the query string, and check whether the "token" key is present.
    if (queryStrings.ContainsKey("token"))
    {
        // Retrieve the photo from the media library using the token passed to the app.
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        Picture photoFromLibrary = library.GetPictureFromToken(queryStrings["token"]);

        // Create a BitmapImage object and add set it as the image control source.
        BitmapImage bitmapFromPhoto = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapFromPhoto.SetSource(photoFromLibrary.GetImage());
        image1.Source = bitmapFromPhoto;
    }
}
```

[GetPathFromToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.medialibraryextensions.getpathfromtoken%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx) should behave in the same way.

Comment: thanks. For example, I took couple of photos. Will each photos are assigned with different tokens by system? How do I figure out what token is associated with which photo? Is this token looks like a absolute path to the physical URI?

Comment: @thsieh check the Photo Share Picker or Photo Edit Picker examples that I linked to, they show how to register extensions so the OS can navigate to your app and they show how to access the token from the query string once the OS has Navigated to your app. For photos this token comes from the "FileId" part of the query string in OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)